# A container view and scroll view present an representation which is offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have an App with an UIScrollView which contains all the UI elements. One of the elements in a Container which has an embedded UIViewController with an UIScrollView containing UIImage and some UILabels drawn on it.

I am having however a problem with the presentation in the UIScrollView of the container, as the UIImage, which is supposed to be filling the whole scrollable content, but there is a bar at the top. This offset is annoying, but also throws off my calculation of the points. (the image is supposed to fill the whole rounder border.

[image]

I set the size (using constrains) of the container view in the ViewDidLoad of the containing UIViewController (and the result, the box, is as expected):

```
[self floorPlanContainerWidthConstraint].constant = [self view].frame.size.width - self.marginWidthConstraint.constant * 2;
if([delegate isiPad]){
    [self floorPlanContainerHeightConstraint].constant = 300;
}
[_floorPlanContainer layoutIfNeeded];
```

Then in the UIViewController of the Container, on ViewWillDisplay, I update the UIImageView dimensions which is contained to the edges of the scrollview with distance '0':

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self imageContainerHeightConstraint].constant = [self parentView].frame.size.height;
[self imageContainerWidthConstraint].constant = [self parentView].frame.size.width;

[_imageView layoutIfNeeded];
[_scrollView layoutIfNeeded];

NSLog(@"Parent frame: %f, %f, location %f, %f", [self parentView].frame.size.width, [self parentView].frame.size.height, [self parentView].frame.origin.x, [self parentView].frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"Image frame: %f, %f, location %f, %f", _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height, _imageView.frame.origin.x, _imageView.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"Scroll frame: %f, %f, location %f, %f", _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height, _scrollView.frame.origin.x, _scrollView.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"Content frame: %f, %f, location %f, %f", _scrollView.contentSize.width, _scrollView.contentSize.height, _scrollView.contentOffset.x, _scrollView.contentOffset.y);
NSLog(@"Scroll frame zoom %f", [_scrollView zoomScale]);
```

The console output is as expected (I think):

```
Parent frame: 351.000000, 200.000000, location 12.000000, 41.000000
Image frame: 351.000000, 200.000000, location 0.000000, 0.000000
Scroll frame: 351.000000, 200.000000, location 0.000000, 0.000000
Content frame: 351.000000, 200.000000, location 0.000000, 0.000000
Scroll frame zoom 1.000000
```

This suggests that the content frame is the same size as the scroll view and image, bu how is it that the content is slightly bigger (the bar as seen) while the values don't support that? I can scroll the image vertically, while it should fit exactly (horizontal it fits).

If I reposition the container view lower on the layout it becomes better, so there is something fishy. I have spend a few hours now trying to figure what is wrong, but cannot find it, so any suggestions are really really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone`.

Comment: This seems in the right direction. However, if I put it in the container view, it does nothing, only in the parent view controller. This would mean the content ends up under the navigation bar, but I could offset this manually.

Comment: @LuukD.Jansen check contained scroll view `contentInset`, maybe it has `top` inset set to nonzero value.